# How to resolve 412 error (Precondition Failed) in Jmeter tool of performance testing?

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, load-testing

PFA Request body:

GET https://sandbox-arrowxl.sugaropencloud.uk/rest/v11_22/Filters?erased_fields=true&max_num=20&filter%255B0%255D%255Bcreated_by%255D=459b76fc-1adc-41b6-b606-2f868093b7da&filter%255B1%255D%255Bmodule_name%255D=PR_Orders

GET data:

Cookie Data:
PHPSESSID=0sjoslbg4mc2on257jrfb9lbs8; download_token_base=TGduwIPh4cvBsABi1dQGqYBRcDCwPMt9kcxpQ0WDuMJ5KCVZXTQAYsGeGl5lpXnu4gcsknjmbRVjMWE5lD6XzgWra_zlhWB1xP1M3_T4tJYdFEoRaP6VYYhoZyjYNVJ_2pmjfNeNmIHgPt13XScCdqVZc1ikqqupLizT9xw

Request Header:

Connection: keep-alive
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
X-Userpref-Hash: 040bb333d34e449dc43435d03e11dded
Referer: https://sandbox-arrowxl.sugaropencloud.uk/
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
X-Metadata-Hash: 982fcdfebdc59c11bce211ebfd6f73d6
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
OAuth-Token: TGduwIPh4cvBsABi1dQGqYBRcDCwPMt9kcxpQ0WDuMJ5KCVZXTQAYsGeGl5lpXnu4gcsknjmbRVjMWE5lD6XzgWra_zlhWB1xP1M3_T4tJYdFEoRaP6VYYhoZyjYNVJ_2pmjfNeNmIHgPt13XScCdqVZc1ikqqupLizT9xw
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Type: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Host: sandbox-arrowxl.sugaropencloud.uk

The response body I am getting:

{"error":"metadata_out_of_date","metadata_hash":"46ce488ee8c453af4c2afb362a256ad4","user_hash":"bcf104cc74fa1e8e01ac8c5750c38a05","error_message":"Your metadata or user hash did not match the server. Please resync your metadata."}

Response Header:

HTTP/1.1 412 Precondition Failed
Date: Tue, 23 Jan 2024 09:38:06 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 230
Connection: keep-alive
Server: Apache
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Status: 412 Precondition Failed
X-Application-Server: cloneuk01-web-1

I have tried correlating the X-Metadata-hash and X-Userpref-Hash. But still getting same error of 412.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to test [SugarCRM](https://www.sugarcrm.com)

According to [this page](https://sugarclub.sugarcrm.com/dev-club/w/dev-tutorials/199/sugar-developer-tools)

> [Sugar Performance Tests](https://github.com/sugarcrm/performance)
>
> This package contains the JMeter based load testing tool for Sugar that is used to measure Sugar performance and validate deployment architecture.

The link gives 404 to me so you might want to contact [SugarCRM developers](https://developers@sugarcrm.com) or customer support in order to get access to scripts.

It might be the case correlation is not sufficient and you will need to calculate the hashes by replicating the underlying logic in the [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) using [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy).